# Grails 2.4.4 - how to redirect from Groovy class (non controller)

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to use **redirect()** method from a Groovy class method which is not resolving in this class, getting Error **groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method**

How I can redirect the control from  a groovy class method to controller-> action inside a project?
not even response object is getting resolved to use response.sendRedirect()

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a bad practise to redirect from service, you can throw an exception in service and catch it in controller to make redirect

Comment: I'm not redirecting from service, it's a security filter class, can you read the question again?

Comment: "groovy class method to controller" where you see security filter? Basically in doFilter method you have response. If you use this filters: https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.3/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html so they work like controller

Comment: @NitinDhomse how / from where you are calling groovy class method ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know is this good way use, but you use following to redirect to controoler action from your groovy class method

```
def yourMethod(){

    new YourController().redirect(action:"YourControllerActionName") 

}
```

Please note that i tested it with grails 3, so please let me is it really worked for you.

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your input, but it didn't  work for me, I just tried with a sample code put print statement inside redirected action, code got executed but didn't get println statement.

Comment: I have also tested from my side it redirected perfectly to my action, i din't tried println